# Binary indicatory between start dates and and end dates in R

Tags: r, date, datetime, dplyr

I have the below dataframe where I am trying to obtain the below-expected output. I am trying to compare `EST_INST_ST_DATE` with the `ST_DATE` if it matches I want to keep the `IS_WITHIN_30DAYS`  column indicator 1 else if `EST_INST_ST_DATE` lies between the month I want to have 1 for the next 2 consecutive months

```
 INPUT 
ID ST_DATE     ND_DATE        EST_INST_ST_DATE
1   2016-01-04   2016-02-03     2016-01-04
1   2016-02-04   2016-03-03     2016-01-04
2   2016-01-04   2016-02-03     2016-01-12
2   2016-02-04   2016-03-03     2016-01-12
2   2016-03-04   2016-04-03     2016-01-12 


Expected output
ID     ST_DATE       ND_DATE     EST_INST_ST_DATE     IS_WITHIN_30DAYS
1     2016-01-04   2016-02-03     2016-01-04               1
1     2016-02-04   2016-03-03     2016-01-04               0
2     2016-01-04   2016-02-03     2016-01-12               1
2     2016-02-04   2016-03-03     2016-01-12               1
2     2016-03-04   2016-04-03     2016-01-12               0
```

I am trying the below code but I am getting error

```
chargefmv5<- chargefmv5 %>% 
  mutate(IS_WITHIN_30DAYS=ifelse((EST_INST_ST_DATE == ST_DATE),1,
                                 ifelse((EST_INST_ST_DATE > ST_DATE & EST_INST_ST_DATE <ND_DATE)),1,0))

Error in ifelse((EST_INST_ST_DATE == ST_DATE), 1, ifelse((EST_INST_ST_DATE >  : 
  unused arguments (1, 0)
```

Comment: The parenthesis is not correct in the second `ifelse`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You closed your second `ifelse` early. Try:

```
chargefmv5 <- chargefmv5 %>%
mutate(IS_WITHIN_30DAYS=ifelse(
  (EST_INST_ST_DATE == ST_DATE),
  1,
  ifelse(
    (EST_INST_ST_DATE > ST_DATE & EST_INST_ST_DATE <ND_DATE),
    1,
    0
  )
)
)
```

Comment: An IDE like Rstudio helps with highlighting matched brackets. It can auto indent too.

Comment: I made a mistake in my data for the new data you code is not working

Comment: your code is correct for the previous data. I made a change in my data I missed some dates which i corrected now it is not working for that